# Change How Files Are Sorted / Listed in a File Manager

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager, nautilus-actions, nautilus-extensions

I work with some directories and files that have patterns such as

```
a-b-c
```

I am wondering if it is possible to sort or search these files by only one of the fields. For example, sorting them by the second field where "b-b-c" would rank above "a-c-a"

I know the sorting and searching part is trivial with the CLI tools. I am looking for a file manager solution specifically. It doesn't have to be Nautilus, if any file manager supports this, I would like to learn about it.

Maybe a Nautilus addon(?), or a file manager with a plugin support where I can drop a bash script to tell it how to sort files for a custom option, or really any application that supports this kind of workflow, even a CLI one.

If I could another field to the list view, it would also be useful. Like a filename that lists "a-b-c", and a "second field" that just says "b" where I can click it to sort by that.

I have checked out Nautilus actions, which seems to be about adding functions to the context menu from what I understand. If I can create a context menu button that changes how the items are listed, that would also be good.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What about renaming files to 001-a-b-c, 002-a-b-a with cli tool, and then use them in file manager? Is it suits?

Comment: In my specific case, it makes sense to want to sort them by the second field for one thing, and the third field for another. So it isn't just "I only care about the second field". I was actually thinking of editing the last modified date field instead, since many Windows programs change that field at will, and thus it isn't really a reliable field. Thanks for the suggestion :)